# Slide old page out as current page slides in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery on a single page web site to slide the next "page" onto the screen when the user clicks a button. I would like the current page to slide out to the left as the new page slides in from the right, so that there is no empty space shown, but currently I am only able to get the current page to disappear as the next page slides in. The code I'm using is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xoa029jz/5/

```
function slideToNext() {
    var currentPage = $('.current-page');
    var nextPage = getNextPage(currentPage.attr('id'));
    $(nextPage).css('display', 'block');
    $(currentPage).animate({left: '-100%'}); 
    $(currentPage).removeClass('current-page');
    $(nextPage).addClass('current-page');
    $(nextPage).animate({left: '0%'});    
}
```

Comment: You are using a combination of CSS transitions *and* jQuery animation. Which would you prefer as they are competing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS transitions are fighting with the jQuery animation. Until I hear which you prefer I have turned off the CSS transition.

The other fixes are to set the initial position of the elements about to animate and to wait for the panel to leave completely before removing the `current-page` class.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xoa029jz/8/

```
function slideToNext() {
    var currentPage = $('.current-page');
    var nextPage = getNextPage(currentPage.attr('id'));
    currentPage.css('left', '0%').animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, function () {
        currentPage.removeClass('current-page');
    });
    nextPage.css({'display': 'block', 'left': '100%'}).addClass('current-page').animate({
        left: '0%'
    });

}
```

I also cleaned up a few redundant items (chained selectors etc).

*You are better off just using jQuery animation, initially while you get it working, then adding a plugin (like [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)) to make the animations use CSS transitions, rather than try to mix the two.*

Comment: not much of an issue but since currentPage variable is already a jQuery object , i don't think we need `$` in front..

    `var currentPage = $('.current-page');
    currentPage.css('left','0%').animate({left: '-100%'}, function()     {
        currentPage.removeClass('current-page');
    });`

Comment: @bipen: Was already cleaning up the initial code, but thanks. Also needed to chain the settings a bit better.